# Enable a textbox when amount entered in the textbox is more than 5000

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 2 textbox one is amount and another is pan card. I am trying to enable a pancard textbox when the amount entered in the amount textbox  is more than 5000. The user as to enter the pan card no only when the amount entered is more than 5000. Otherwise the textbox as to be disabled. Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#amount").onkeydown(function(){
    var amount=$("#amount").val();
    if(amount>=5000){
        $("#pan").attr('diasbled',false);
    }

});

</script>
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
<input type="text" name="pan" id="pan" disabled>
```

Comment: `.val()` will return a string. Cast to number, and consider using `type="number"` in the HTML as well

Comment: `disabled` not `diasbled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$("#amount").change(function(){
    var amount = parseInt($("#amount").val());
    if(amount >= 5000){
        $("#pan").removeAttr('disabled');
    }

});
```

Initially you need the jQuery's change event handler, then you have to use javascript's built-in parseInt function in order to get to amount as an integer and finally you have to use jQuery's removeAttr function.

Comment: @user3168637 It does work. Feel free to try out this jsFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/m9opd6b7/18/

Comment: It works fine in jsFiddle but when I add it in my code it doesnt work

Comment: Probably you should start debugging to see in which line the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#amount").onkeydown(function(){

 // here the $('#amount').val() will return string '5000' in your case. To convert to Number you can use parseInt() or Number() in Javascript.

  var amount= parseInt($("#amount").val());

  if(!isNaN(amount) && amount >= 5000){
    $("#pan").attr('diasbled',false);
  }

 });

</script>
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
<input type="text" name="pan" id="pan" disabled>
```

More detials about [Number](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) [isNaN](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)